# Trouble enabling display_error in php.ini

Tags: apache-2.2, php, php.ini

I'm trying to enable PHP error output to the browser. phpinfo() shows that the path to php.ini is /etc/httpd/php.ini. So as root I edited it by adding a line:

```
display_errors = On
```

I restarted apache and it still didn't work, phpinfo() was showing that display_errors was Off  both as local and master values. I rebooted my computer and the problem was still there.

If I add

```
ini_set("display_errors","1");
ERROR_REPORTING(E_ALL);
```

to my script it shows the errors, phpinfo() shows that display_errors as local value is On, but I'd like to find out why the php.ini solution isn't working. I don't know if it's relevant, but here's the permission settings to php.ini:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 48267 Oct 10 00:22 php.ini
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps directive "display_errors" defined twice in php.ini:

```
grep -i display_errors /etc/httpd/php.ini
```

Answer (score 1):

As bindbn recommended, checking for duplicate directives in php.ini is a good start - then check the [other places PHP configuration directives may be set](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to follow [Can't get PHP to stop showing errors](https://serverfault.com/questions/307793/) and [php 7 ignores ini files, but claims to load](https://serverfault.com/questions/783883/)

1. What is "Loaded Configuration File" -> check that you edit the correct ini-file
2. check for multiple occurences of display_errors in the same file.
3. Check permissions on the ini file. The web server needs read access.
4. php 5 and later: try `sudo service php-fpm restart` before testing