# Can't get PHP to stop showing errors

Tags: php, configuration, php.ini

Contrary to most people's problem I cannot get PHP to stop showing errors, I have in my php.ini display_errors set to off but it still shows them, I have also tried .htaccess, and inline ini_set and error_reporting variables but the errors still show.

What can I do to prevent this overide?

Mac OS X Lion Server 10.7.1
MAMP Compiled using instructions from DIY Mac Server (diymacserver.com)

UPDATE:

This is where my php.ini file is stored...

[image: This is where my php.ini is]

This is the value of my display_errors setting at run time

[image: This is the value of my display_errors]

And this is the copy and paste value written in /etc/php.ini

```
display_errors = Off
```

Comment: Have you checked `phpinfo()` to make sure you're using the same php.ini that PHP is using (also, whether it says its on or off)?

Comment: I had not but I have now and it was correct, I changed short tags to on in there and that worked so it's working and reading the file, but its not adhering to the settings for error reporting.

Comment: I have added some more detail about my configuration

Comment: I have managed to figure out that its happening because my php.ini isn't being read although its in place, can anyone suggest what permissions would be correct for a Apache 2 install running as _www in the group _www (mac os x)

Answer (score 2):

make sure your editing the right php.ini file as there are two ini files, one for apache and one for CLI.

Comment: Yes I am editing the right file, as I managed to enable short tags successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I came across similar behaviour recently and found out that the php.ini layout is quite confusing: listing of the default values etc. is at the top of the file while description of the setting and the setting itself are way further down. (see [php 7 ignores ini files, but claims to load](https://serverfault.com/questions/783883/)).

1. It could well be that a later setting overrides yours. Browse or search the ini file for all occurences of "display_errors": `grep -n display_errors/etc/php.ini`
2. What is the value of "Loaded Configuration File "?

Answer (score 0):

The `display_errors` directive can be altered at runtime with the [ini_set](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) function. Make sure that none of the code is turning error display back on.

Also, when you update php.ini settings, make sure to restart Apache.

Comment: Indeed it can and I have tried that but it still shows errors...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an `auto_append_file=` setting that is causing php to include code on every page that uses `ini_set()` to turn the display back on?

Comment: It is set to blank

Answer (score 0):

It is worth bearing in mind that even if you don't display or log errors, they still have a big impact on throughput and performance.

The 3 most obvious causes are:

1) you are changing the wrong php.ini file (which you've already addressed).

2) the php.ini setting is over-ridden somewhere else - if this is mod_php then that could be in the httpd.conf files or .htaccess

3) you didn't restart the PHP process (httpd when we're talking about mod_php) after making the changes