# php.ini changes don't have any effect

Tags: apache-2.2, php, php.ini

When I make any changes in php.ini located in /usr/local/lib on centos, the changes don't appear to be applied, for example, when I clear all the content of php.ini and restart Apache everything works fine...

I searched for php.ini and it is in one place in system... what's the problem? How can I fix this?

Comment: How did you search for this file? What command did you use? What paths did you look into?

Comment: @Khaled i searched with this way:  whereis php.ini

Comment: How many php.ini's do you have (E.g. check with `find / -name php.ini -print`).

Comment: Try `find /etc -name php.ini`.

Comment: i have only one at: /usr/local/lib/php.ini

Answer (score 14, accepted):

if you're unsure what php.ini is being used, create a new file in your webfolder, name it `phpinfo.php` for example , with the following content

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

then open the url in your browser (http://www.example.com/phpinfo.php). it will show the path to the php.ini being used.

when you have identified the correct file, make your desired changes, and be sure to remove the leading ; in case there is one to activate the setting.

restart apache and reload the phpinfo page, your changed setting should now show up. if it doesn't, make sure you don't have a .htaccess file in your webroot that overrides php settings.

Comment: i do this an this is output:
Configuration File (php.ini) Path /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File               /usr/local/lib/php.ini

Comment: what value did you try to change? did you remove the leading ';' to activate the setting?

Comment: Isn't omitting the ending tag of php `?>` a good practice?

Comment: This was very important to solve my version of this problem - I was using command line `php --ini` but it was pointing to a different file than used by the webserver (Apache2)

Answer (score 10):

You may want to read these threads:

- [Can't get PHP to stop showing errors](https://serverfault.com/questions/307793/)
- [php 7 ignores ini files, but claims to load](https://serverfault.com/questions/783883/)
- [Trouble enabling display_error in php.ini](https://serverfault.com/questions/189436/)

hints:

1. What is "Loaded Configuration File" in php_info output? -> check that you edit the correct ini-file.
2. check for multiple occurences of your setting in the same file.
3. Gryphius´s hint is not bad either: Uncomment the setting! (remove the leading ";")
4. Check permissions on the ini file. The web server and php-cgi/php-fpm need read access.
5. php 5 and later: Do not only restart the web server, but also the php-fpm service before testing.

Comment: I just switched to fast-cgi and restarting fpm did the trick, thanks.

Comment: Yes point 5 is the unusual step. Thanks.

Comment: Point 5 was the solution for me as well ! I tried everything else on my own, and noticed that changes only take effect after a full reboot. Just wasn't sure which service needs to be restarted to take effect! Thank you

Comment: On Amazon linux, restarted both `httpd` (apache) and `php-fpm` and still no effect. `php_info` says `/etc/php.ini` is the loaded config file. I've changed it, deleted it, no effect. Finally, I used "grep -lr 'display_errors'" to see if the directive was contained anywhere else. Found it in `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`. As such: `php_flag[display_errors] = on`. Commented that line, restarted php-fpm (no need to restart apache, apparently), and finally my errors are not being shown to the world.

Answer (score 2):

I found a very blatant error in my `php.ini` file which caused this very symptom, eg. some php.ini settings did not take effect..

As of php7.0, the `#` character is not a valid comment starter. Only `;` is accepted. But still many editors, for example `vim`, show characters after "`#`" as comments so you may not recognise that a certain part of the php.ini file is not an ignorable comment.

In my case, the `php.ini` filed contained this:

```
# ""
max_input_vars = 3000
```

The `max_input_vars = 3000` did not take effect because the previous line is not a comment. It has some side-effect which causes my next line to be ignored.

Changing it to

```
; ""
max_input_vars = 3000
```

solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using apache you should know there are 2 ini files:

```
/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini
```

and

```
/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
```

You should change the one in `/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini`

***replace 7.4 with your php version***

Answer (score 1):

Follow this:

Create a file inside your webroot naming it whatever you want. I usually prefer x.php

```
 # vim x.php
```

The contents of the file should be this:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Now open this file in your browser like this:

```
http://server_ip/x.php
```

This will show you the location of the php.ini your apache is using.
Edit that php.ini and it will work.

Comment: i do this an this is output:
Configuration File (php.ini) Path /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File               /usr/local/lib/php.ini

Comment: That means you are using this file only. Any changes to this file will be reflected in Apache. You can test the same with the same URL. Make some change in some variable in this php.ini, and that will be reflected in x.php file in browser.

Answer (score 0):

you might have php.ini file in your webroot.

Answer (score 0):

cannot comment here yet, but:
Does it work if you keep the changes and restart Apache?

If so, the reason is probably that PHP runs as an Apache module.
If you want changes to have effect without restarting the web server, use php-cgi instead.

[This page](http://www.thesitewizard.com/php/install-php-5-apache-windows.shtml) explains installation and configuration; search the page for "as an Apache Module" or for "PHP 5 as a CGI Binary".