# php 7 ignores ini files, but claims to load

Tags: php.ini

Ubuntu 16.04, Lighty 1.4.35, PHP 7.0.4-7ubuntu2 (in a Hyper-V VM)

I browsed all (or at least many) of the other questions about php.ini.

---

No matter what value I set for any of the directives; ini_get returns does not necessarily return that value. And php´s behaviour doesn´t seem to have anything to do with either of them.

- no error messages in browsers, although `display_errors` is On by default. (php_info shows "Off" in the browser and on CLI)
- full error messages (including notices) are listed on CLI and written to the server log, although the default value for `error_reporting` excludes `E_NOTICE`. (And php_info displays the default value, no matter what I put in any php.ini file)
- all messages are written to the lighttpd/error.log, although `log_errors` is Off by default. And no matter what I set it to): php_info() says it´s on.

---

php -h tells, that `php -c <path>|<file>` can be used to change the ini file path. calling info.php with PHP CLI

- with no other parameters: Config File Path: CLI, Loaded Config File: CLI
- with `-c /etc/php/7.0/fpm/ini.php`: File Path: CLI, Loaded: (none)
- with `-c /etc/php/7.0/fpm/`: File Path: (still !!) CLI, Loaded: FPM

It all works well on my old machine (Ubuntu 14.04.4, Lighty 1.4.33, PHP 7.0.7-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+1); but I cannot find anything in the PHP 7 ChangeLog that would explain my problems.

Any ideas while I inspect the other included ini files one by one?

Comment: `phpinfo()` tells you what INI files are being parsed. Maybe you have the wrong ones.

Comment: There are only three php,ini files on the machine; and I edited them all. The mistake isn´t beatable on stupidity.

Comment: I'm not sure what "the mistake isn't beatable on stupidity" means, but I'd encourage you to peruse `phpinfo()`'s output anyways. It should show what folder it expects `.ini` files in. The three you edited may still not be the ones it's looking in.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `grep -n error_reporting` on the ini file revealed everything:

error_reporting default, development and production settings are described in php.ini around line 105.

I added my setting on line 111.

And there had already been a setting more than 300 lines below that, which overrode my setting.

*TILT*

Answer (score 0):

If php-fpm runs as a daemon, restart it to reload php.ini

Comment: yes this problem drove me nuts for a fair bit on a new CentOS 8 installation.

service php-fpm restart will make it read the edited php.ini file

Comment: @Anthony I'm on Amazon Linux which is like CentOS and restarting php-fpm isn't doing it for me either.

Comment: I found the problem in `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`. This line: `php_flag[display_errors] = on`. Commented that line, restarted php-fpm (no need to restart apache, apparently), and finally my errors are not being shown to the world.

Answer (score 0):

This might be silly, but I was on AWS and I had to restart the instance to get `php.ini` reloaded.